# Replace one string list with list of strings in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a list `["a","b","c","a"]` where I want to replace `"a"` with `["a_1","b_1","c_1"]` such that the list becomes `["a_1","b_1","c_1","b","c", "a_1","b_1","c_1"]`

What is the fastest way to do this in python?

Comment: do you want to replace every `"a"` in the list?  If the input list is different, should that change what you replace `"a"` with?

Comment: yes you are correct. I have modified my example

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a comprehension with `chain.from_iterable` and a ternary statement:

```
from itertools import chain

L = list('abca')  # ['a', 'b', 'c', 'a']

rep_key, rep_val = ('a', ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1'])
res = list(chain.from_iterable([i] if i != rep_key else rep_val for i in L))

['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to *mutate* your list, then you can rely on slicing. This will indeed *replace* elements in your list, not create a new one.

```
lst = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
a_indices = [i for i, c in enumerate(lst) if c == "a"]

for i in reversed(a_indices):
    lst[i:i+1] = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']

print(lst) # ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a simple for loop:

```
l = ["a", "b", "c", "a"]
for i in range(len(l)):
    if l[i] == "a":
        l[i] = "a_1"
        l+=["b_1", "c_1"]
```

---

```
>>> l
['a_1', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a good place for a simple generator function:

```
def lazy_replace(L, char, val):
    for item in L:
        if item == char:
            yield from val
        else:
            yield item
```

---

```
>>> L = list('abca')
>>> val = ['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
>>> list(lazy_replace(L, 'a', val))
['a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1', 'b', 'c', 'a_1', 'b_1', 'c_1']
```